# C# - Getting AD account status results in NullReferenceException for int value that is not null

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm getting a list of every user account in Active Directory with the code shown here. I'm specifically checking the account status so I can have a "enabled" or "disabled" icon in my WinForm list view:

```
var domainName = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
MessageBox.Show(domainName);

PrincipalContext domainContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName);
{
    using (UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(domainContext))
    {
        using (PrincipalSearcher pS = new PrincipalSearcher())
        {
            pS.QueryFilter = user;

            foreach (var result in pS.FindAll())
            {
                try
                { 
                    ListViewItem tmpItem = null;
                    
                    Principal pc = result;
                    DirectoryEntry child = (DirectoryEntry)pc.GetUnderlyingObject();

                    int flag = (int)child.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;
                    bool disabled = Convert.ToBoolean(flag & 0x0002);

                    if (disabled == false)
                    {
                        tmpItem = new ListViewItem(new string[] {
                        (string)child.Properties["givenName"].Value,
                        (string)child.Properties["sn"].Value,
                        (string)child.Properties["samAccountName"].Value
                        }, (int)AdImages.User);
                        this.listView_ad.Items.Add(tmpItem);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        tmpItem = new ListViewItem(new string[] {
                        (string)child.Properties["givenName"].Value,
                        (string)child.Properties["sn"].Value,
                        (string)child.Properties["samAccountName"].Value
                        }, (int)AdImages.block);
                        this.listView_ad.Items.Add(tmpItem);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When debugging on a test DC, I'm getting the below error but form what I can see, the `int` flag is being assigned a value (in the below case, `66048` so I don't understand why it's crashing out with the error?

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's crashing out with a 66048 error.  It looks like you're getting a NullReferenceException trying to access child.Properties["userAccountControll"].value.  Which means any of 1) child, OR 2) child.Properties OR 3) child.Properties["userAccountControl"] might be "null".

Comment: 66048 is the value from `child.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value` so can't see `child` or `child.Properties` can be null?

Comment: Although the usage scope of `flag` is limited to the try-block, the value is stored local to the method body. The `66048` value is from the previous iteration of the `foreach`. To prove this to yourself, change the code to `int flag = 0; flag = (int)child.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value;`.

Comment: @Rawns: no, no, no! Like  TnTinMn suggested, your "66048" is likely from the *preceding* child!  Just set a breakpoint at the "int flag = ..." line, and examine the "bad value" 
 to determine exactly which part of your expression is "null".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't be silly like me. Run Visual Studio as Administrator...

The above was working. Just needed to run as Admin and every `userAccountControl` value for every account was then returned.